# Why are $p$ orbitals independent from this symmetry rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, orbitals

I am very new to quantum mechanics and I have a question about $p$ orbitals.

I am studying Beiser's *Modern Physics* and according to that in the Bohr Model the wave the probability density of azimuthal angle is constant so the wave function should be independent to the azimuthal angle and be symmetric along the $xy$ plane.

In the case of $p$ orbitals, $p_z$ is symmetric in the $xy$ plane but $p_x$ and $p_y$ vary along the $xy$ plane. How is this possible?

Comment: I don't think the Bohr model has p orbitals at all. Or even really orbitals for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am studying Beiser's *Modern Physics* and according to that in the Bohr Model the wave the probability density of ...

This is a misunderstanding of the text. There are no probabilities, no waves, and no orbitals in the Bohr model. Your question makes perfect sense, but it is inscribed within full-grown QM ─ it has nothing to do with the Bohr model.

> the wave the probability density of azimuthal angle is constant so the wave function should be independent to the azimuthal angle and be symmetric along the $xy$ plane.
>
> In the case of $p$ orbitals, $p_z$ is symmetric in the $xy$ plane but $p_x$ and $p_y$ vary along the $xy$ plane. How is this possible?

The term "$p$ orbital" can mean several slightly-different things depending on the context. The mismatch here comes from taking objects from one of these and expecting them to have the properties of the others.

In general, "$p$ orbital" means an orbital which is an eigenstate of the total angular momentum, $L^2$. This includes the $p_z$ orbital as well as the $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals.

The property that you mention (invariance of the orbitals' probability distribution with respect to rotations around the $z$ axis) is not true of general $p$ orbitals in the sense I just described ─ it is a property of the simultaneous eigenstates of $L^2$ and $L_z$. This includes $p_z$ but it does not include $p_x$ and $p_y$; instead, for the subspace spanned by those two, you have to use the combinations
\begin{align}
p_+ & = \frac{p_x+ip_y}{\sqrt 2}  \\
\text{and } \quad p_- & = \frac{p_x-ip_y}{\sqrt 2},
\end{align}
for which the invariance does hold.